# How to send all traffic to a proxy that requires authentication with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a proxy server that authenticates with username and password. I want to receive all requests on localhost:4040 through Nginx and transfer them to the upstream server.

```
events {}
http {
    
    
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  300;

    proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  server {
    listen *:443;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;
  
  server {
        listen 4040;
        listen [::]:4040;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://202.28.17.5:8080;
                proxy_set_header Proxy-Authorization "Basic czYxMTEwMTI2MTAyODI6MDgyNTg2NDY3N21pbGQ="; 
         }
    }


}
```

I use Firefox "Configure Proxy Access to the Internet" for test upstream proxy and its working,
But when I set localhost:4040 in Firefox proxy its not working.